# Entity Framework missing ObjectSet methods

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I imported a project from SVN, constructed a MSSQL CE 4.0 local database from a script provided with the project, generated the Entity Model using [SQL Server CE Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/), checked the connexion string, checked the assemblies, but yet some methods are missing from the generated `ObjectSet` entities.

From [Microsoft's site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719.aspx), there should be a method `Any<TEntity>()`, but I it's not there.

Here's the simple test I'm doing :

```
using (Dbntities ctx = new DbEntities())
{
   List<User> Users = ctx.Users.All();
}
```

And Visual Studio 2010 cannot compile because the method `All()` does not exist.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

First: Make sure to add the needed using statement as [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534754.aspx) is an extension method of `IQueryable<T>`:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Second: Use the `All` method with the right parameters:

```
List<User> Users = ctx.Users.All(x => x.Foo == "foo");
```

Comment: the first one. I was missing the `using`. Weird that VS2010 did not suggest it...

Comment: @YanickRochon. May I suggest [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) which adds the using almost automatically?

Comment: looks nice! I will definitely consider it. Thanks!